# Можно ли переменной const в JS присваивать значение Повторно?

Tags: javascript

Ребята, я Абсолютный Новичок, в JS, поэтому Будьте Снисходительны!! И НЕ бейте по рукам!!
В обучающем видео смотрел, что при Повторном присвоении значения переменной const - должна выскакивать Ошибка.....
Но у меня в Хром-консоли НИкакой ошибки Нет, а Переприсвается значение....

Что я не так понимаю? - подскажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и есть, вот пример кода - при переназначении переменной выводиться ошибка. Вы можете так же попробовать вбить этот код прям в консоли браузера - будет ошибка.

```js
const i = 10;
i = 5;
```

Comment: Спасибо вам больше

Comment: Не так вводил...

Comment: Пометье ответ как правильный если он вам помог ))

Comment: Да. Сейчас сделаю...... - только Начинаю разбираться на сайте,,,,,

Comment: Получается можно посетить как правильный только Один ответ?..... Печально.

Comment: Вы можете поставить плюс за несколько ответов, это тоже пойдет отвечающим в карму

Comment: Ещё раз Спасибо, что подсказываете!

Comment: А вы мне можете ещё объяснить - как увеличить размер шрифта (или саму консоль) в Visual Studio?..... Значка % внизу нет..... В хром консоле Crtl+. В Visual Studio это НЕ работает,,,,,,,

Comment: Задайте отдельно вопрос,  кто нибудь откликнется. я не работаю с этой IDE

Comment: понятно. спасибо

Comment: @Gazovchik, [ctrl] + [-] / [ctrl] + [=].

Comment: Oliver - Спасибо вам!!

Answer (score 1):

Надо понимать, что `const` работает в том случае, если меняется значение самой переменной, но если в переменной находится объект и менять непосредственно **свойство объекта**, то это не будет считаться за изменение переменной, т.к. сам тип остался объектом, который указывает всё на ту же область памяти.

Так что возможно у вас была такая проблема именно с объектом, а не с каким-нибудь примитивом

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Например ошибки не будет в таком случае:

```js
const myArray = [0, true, 'hi', null, 999];       //создадим 'константу'
console.log(`Первоначальный массив: ${myArray}`); //проверим содержимое

myArray[2] = 15;                                  //изменим значение 'hi' на 15
console.log(`Изменённый массив: ${myArray}`);     //проверим содержимое снова
```

Но код не выполнится в таком:

```js
const myArray = [0, true, 'hi', null, 999];       //создадим 'константу'
console.log(`Первоначальный массив: ${myArray}`); //проверим содержимое

myArray = [0, true, 15, null, 999];               //попробуем изменить значение 'hi' на 15
console.log(`Изменённый массив: ${myArray}`);     //проверим содержимое снова
```

Все потому что в языке существуют разные типы данных:

1. Примитивы - передают значение(числа, строки, булевы значения и
   т.д.)
2. Объекты - передают ссылку на значение(объекты, массивы,
   функции и т.д.)

Когда объявляешь в качестве константы объектный тип данных, в константу записывается ссылка на значения, а не сами значения. Поэтому их возможно изменять. Однако во 2 примере мы не меняли значения массива, а пытались присвоить константе новый массив с новой ссылкой. Из-за этой попытки изменить ссылку на массив и случилась ошибка.

Больше про типы данных можно узнать здесь: [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: Просто, какое-то только можно, большое спасибо за такой подробный ответ!